# How to make Clang-Format insert line break before : operator in class / struct

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm trying to format some code with clang-format 3.7.

I have a struct that looks a bit like this:

```
struct NameOfStruct
{
  explicit NameOfStruct()
    : Thing1(-1), Thing2(-1)
  {}

  std::size_t objectA;
  std::size_t objectB;
};
```

This is fine, but clang-format insists on formatting it like this:

```
struct NameOfStruct
{
  explicit NameOfStruct() : Thing1(-1), Thing2(-1)
  {
  }

  std::size_t objectA;
  std::size_t objectB;
};
```

I would much rather have `Thing1` and `Thing2` on the next line and would prefer to have the braces on the same line but I can live without that.

This is my current `.clang-format` file, is there any way to change this?

```
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  Google
AccessModifierOffset: -1
AlignAfterOpenBracket: true
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: true
AlignOperands:   true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: true
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
ColumnLimit:     120
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DerivePointerAlignment: true
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
ForEachMacros:   [ foreach, Q_FOREACH, BOOST_FOREACH ]
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
Language: Cpp
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: All 
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: false
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 1
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 200
PointerAlignment: Left
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Cpp11
TabWidth:        8
UseTab:          Never
```

Comment: C is not C++ is not C. Do not add tags for unrelated languages.

Comment: I am very aware of this and usually comment the exact same thing. But I did explain why both tags were used. Clang-format is useable on both languages and this problem may come up in both. The solution will be applicable to both and therefore I thought both tags were appropriate. Apologies if this is incorrect.

Comment: C has no member initializer lists, so this problem cannot come up in that language. And as a side note, ClangFormat is not very customizable. If you want that much control over your formatting, maybe look at Uncrustify.

Comment: Right! Gotcha, thanks Zenith. Shows how long it's been since I used C... Will take a look at Uncrustify. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have `BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false` where you want `true`.